# Exclude part of string between 2 symbols within "selected string" via regex?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a text file formatted like this:

```
   "random shit text@[text i'm trying to ignore]some more random shit text": "",
   "random shit text@[text i'm trying to ignore]some more random shit text": "",
   "random shit text@[text i'm trying to ignore]some more random shit text": "",
```

been using "([^"]*\S)" to select everything between "" that isn't empty, but is it possible to make it ignore this part:

```
@[text i'm trying to ignore]
```

so the output I would get is:

```
"random shit textsome more random shit text"
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: What exactly delineates the text you done want?

Comment: Did anything work for you? Please update the question if not.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is impossible.

After extraction of these strings, run a second replace step with:

```js
@\[[^\]\[]*\]
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/VEAxPZ/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @                        '@'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\]\[]*                 any character except: '\]', '\[' (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \]                       ']'
```